# WC_Product_Query return empty in functions.php but working in archive-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, product

Am using WooCommerce 3.6.5.

I need all variable products in my functions.php file so for this I want to use WC_Product_Query in my functions.php file but it always return the empty data. But the same code working in WooCommerce template files (archive-product.php) and return correct data.

here is my code

```
$query = new WC_Product_Query(array(
            'limit'=>-1,
            'type' => 'variable',
            'return' => 'ids'
        ));
        $variableproducts = $query->get_products();
        echo '<pre>';
echo 'print from functions.php';
print_r($variableproducts);
echo '</pre>';
```

can anyone help me why `WC_Product_Query` class not return correct data in functions.php or is there any another way to get all variable products ids in functions.php file?

Answer (score 0):

here is another way of doing this using wc_get_products:

```
$args = array(
'type' => 'variable',
'limit' => -1,
'return' => 'ids',
);
$variable_products_ids = wc_get_products( $args );
```

your code should also work. problem may be the hook you're using. you should also debug it.
this code adds all variable ids to all posts contents.

```
add_filter('the_content' , function ($cnt){
    $args = array(
'type' => 'variable',
'limit' => -1,
'return' => 'ids',
);
$variable_products_ids = wc_get_products( $args );
$str = '';
foreach($variable_products_ids as $id){
    $str .= $id . ' ';
}
return $cnt .' '. $str;
}
);
```

Comment: I have tried wc_get_products also, but result is same.